# Debugging STM32 using QT Creator

Tags: debugging, qt-creator, stm32, bare-metal

I'v decided to try Qt Creator with ARM GCC toolchain. I'v managed to setup a QBS project, it's built and a firmware is downloaded successfully. In addition, I use STM32F3-Discovery with STM32F303VCT on the board. But I can't debug the project because of following reasons:

1. Breakpoints don't work. Process don't stop.
2. I can't step in source files, only in Disassembler. Qt Creator switch to Disassembler itself, when I'm trying to step in Main.c.

How can I setup the Debugger to see registers, add  Watch, set and clear bits in registers manually like in Keil or Eclipse? So, could anybody help? Thanks.
P.S. Here is my Start.qbs

```
import qbs

Product
{
       type: ["application", "flash"]
       Depends { name: "cpp" }

       cpp.defines: ["STM32F30X_LD_VL"]
       cpp.positionIndependentCode: false
       cpp.enableExceptions: false
       cpp.executableSuffix: ".elf"
cpp.driverFlags:
[
    "-mthumb",
    "-mcpu=cortex-m4",
    "-mfloat-abi=soft",
    "-fno-strict-aliasing",
    "-g3",
    "-Wall",
    "-mfpu=vfp",
    "-Og",
    "-flto",
]

cpp.commonCompilerFlags:
[
    "-fdata-sections",
    "-ffunction-sections",
    "-fno-inline",
    "-std=c99",
    "-flto"
]

cpp.linkerFlags:
[
    "-specs=nano.specs",
    "--start-group",
    "--gc-sections",
    "-T" + path + "/STM32F303VCTx_FLASH.ld",
    "-lnosys",
    "-lgcc",
    "-lc",
    "-lstdc++",
    "-lm"
]

cpp.includePaths:
[
    "Inc",
    "Drivers/CMSIS/Include",
    "Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F3xx/Include",
    "Drivers/STM32F3xx_HAL_Driver/Inc"
]

files:
[
    "Inc/*.h",
    "Drivers/CMSIS/Include/*.h",
    "Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F3xx/Include/*.h",
    "Drivers/STM32F3xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/*.h",
    "Drivers/STM32F3xx_HAL_Driver/Src/*.c",
    "Src/*.c",
    "*.s"
]

Properties
{
    condition: qbs.buildVariant === "debug"
    cpp.defines: outer.concat(["DEBUG=1"])
    cpp.debugInformation: true
    cpp.optimization: "none"
}

Properties
{
    condition: qbs.buildVariant === "release"
    cpp.debugInformation: false
    cpp.optimization: "small"
}

Rule
{
    inputs: ["application"]

    Artifact
    {
        filePath: project.path + "/debug/bin/" + input.baseName + ".hex"
        fileTags: "flash"
    }

    prepare:
    {
        var sizePath = "C:/Users/kushnir/AppData/Roaming/gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2017-q4-major-win32/bin/arm-none-eabi-size.exe";
        var objcopyPath = "C:/Users/kushnir/AppData/Roaming/gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2017-q4-major-win32/bin/arm-none-eabi-objcopy.exe";
        var configStlinkPath = "C:/openocd-0.10.0/scripts/interface/stlink-v2-1.cfg";
        var configStm32Path = "C:/openocd-0.10.0/scripts/target/stm32f3x.cfg";
        var flashPath = "C:/openocd-0.10.0/bin-x64/openocd.exe";

        var argsSize = [input.filePath];
        var argsObjcopy = ["-O", "ihex", input.filePath, output.filePath];

       var argsFlashing =
        [
            "-f", configStlinkPath,
            "-f", configStm32Path,
            "-c", "init",
            "-c", "halt",
            "-c", "flash erase_sector 0 0 127",
            "-c", "reset",
            "-c", "halt",
            "-c", "flash write_image " + input.filePath,
            "-c", "verify_image " + input.filePath,
            "-c", "reset",
            "-c", "exit"
        ];

        var cmdSize = new Command(sizePath, argsSize);
        var cmdObjcopy = new Command(objcopyPath, argsObjcopy);
        var cmdFlash = new Command(flashPath, argsFlashing);

        cmdSize.description = "Size of sections:";
        cmdSize.highlight = "linker";

        cmdObjcopy.description = "convert to bin...";
        cmdObjcopy.highlight = "linker";

        cmdFlash.description = "download firmware to uC...";
        cmdFlash.highlight = "linker";

        return [cmdSize, cmdObjcopy, cmdFlash];
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you have incorrectly configured optimization settings for the Debug mode. The variable cpp.debugInformation is set when the compiler starts, based on which compiler mode was selected in the QtCreator. I would replace the code

```
Properties
{
    condition: qbs.buildVariant === "debug"
    cpp.defines: outer.concat(["DEBUG=1"])
    cpp.debugInformation: true
    cpp.optimization: "none"
}

Properties
{
    condition: qbs.buildVariant === "release"
    cpp.debugInformation: false
    cpp.optimization: "small"
}
```

to the next:

```
Properties {
    // Debug
    condition: cpp.debugInformation
    cpp.defines: outer.concat(["DEBUG=1"])
    cpp.optimization: "none"
}
// Release
cpp.optimization: "small"
```

I have this code works very well.

Comment: Thank you, but nothing has changed.

Comment: More ideas? Seems like GDB doesn't work as it should. I have GDB 8.0

Comment: Please check output file size for both builds (release and debug). I think your debug build don't work correctly

Comment: You mean .bg files?

Comment: I mean output .hex file and .elf file. Last is a most importante for debuging

Comment: elf file is 130KB, hex - 15KB

Comment: In what mode? Debug or related release?

Comment: Also I'v tried building an another project on Ubuntu work station and I was successful, but instead of Openocd I'v used St-link util. Unfortunately I cuoldn't find how to watch IO registers for example. Is it even possible?

Comment: I was talking of Debug